# angularjs advanced ng-options with filter

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have this json object:

```
    {  
      "title":"Training Pants",
      "modifiers":[  
         {  
            "id":"1172499777372291315",
            "type":"variant",
            "title":"Gender",
            "variants":[  
               {  
                  "id":"1172499862214672628",
                  "modifierId":"1172499777372291315",
                  "title":"Male"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172499953986044150",
                  "modifierId":"1172499777372291315",
                  "title":"Female"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172500083497763064",
                  "modifierId":"1172499777372291315",
                  "title":"Junior"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":"1172500938313695482",
            "type":"single",
            "title":"Cuffs",
            "variants":[  
               {  
                  "id":"1172501102411645179",
                  "modifierId":"1172500938313695482",
                  "title":"Elasticated"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172501247098355967",
                  "modifierId":"1172500938313695482",
                  "title":"Combination"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172501400207229187",
                  "modifierId":"1172500938313695482",
                  "title":"Open End"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":"1172501710124351751",
            "type":"single",
            "title":"Pockets",
            "variants":[  
               {  
                  "id":"1172501859257024776",
                  "modifierId":"1172501710124351751",
                  "title":"Open Side"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172502043185643794",
                  "modifierId":"1172501710124351751",
                  "title":"Zipped Side"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":"1172502381967966492",
            "type":"single",
            "title":"Accessories",
            "variants":[  
               {  
                  "id":"1172502597169316125",
                  "modifierId":"1172502381967966492",
                  "title":"Waist Cord"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172502756494147870",
                  "modifierId":"1172502381967966492",
                  "title":"No.5 Chunky Zip (12\" Leg)"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"1172502919115702559",
                  "modifierId":"1172502381967966492",
                  "title":"No.5 Chunky Zip (18\" Leg)"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
    }
```

As you can see, it has an array of **modifiers**. I need to filter out the **modifers** by type and only select the **variant**.
I wrote my ng-repeat like this:

```
 ng-options="gender.title as gender.title for gender in filters = (item.garment.modifiers | filter: { type: 'variant' })"
```

but that isn't quite what I want. What I actually want is the **variants** within the **modifier**. I was hoping I could just do this:

```
 ng-options="gender.title as gender.title for gender in filters.variants = (item.garment.modifiers | filter: { type: 'variant' })"
```

but that didn't work.
Is there a simple way of doing this or do I have to create a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
ng-options="gender.title as gender.title for gender in filters = (item.garment.modifiers | filter: { type: 'variant' }).variants"
```

Comment: close :D it was `ng-options="gender.title as gender.title for gender in filters = (item.garment.modifiers | filter: { type: 'variant' })[0].variants"`